# Styled Components render background color conditionally

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, conditional-operator

I think the piece of code is self explanatory:

```
const TheSearchForm = styled.form`
    input[type="text"]:focus {
        ${({ navItemsColor }) =>
          navItemsColor == "white" && {
            backgroundColor: "black",
          }}
    }`;
```

So, when `navItemsColor` is "white" i want `backgroundColor` to be "black" and vice versa, but this code is not working.

I also tried:

```
const TheSearchForm = styled.form`

       input[type="text"]:focus {
        background-color: ${({ navItemsColor }) =>
          navItemsColor === "white" ? "black" : "white"}
        }`;
```

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean the code is not working? What does the rendered CSS look like? (Open devtools.) Got any errors? How are you using the component?

Comment: Maybe is for this reason you forgot the semicolon at the end of styling for `background`.

Comment: @code not working means its not doing what i intend to do. So, its not setting the background color to black or white. I also didn't ask for help here just the first time it didn't work. I'm having devtools opened all the time tracking every change. There's no `background-color` property at all in devtools when i try to set it this way. Otherwise, when i just set it manually `background-color: white` it works. So theres something wrong how im doing the conditional function. Also all my other `navItems` work based on the `navItemsColor` prop im passing from the parent component.

Comment: I agree 100% with @ArmanEbrahimi. You forgot the ending semicolon. Good catch.

Comment: Just fixed it. It wasn't the semicolon. I forgot to pass the `navItemsColor` prop through a middle component. I didn't track the path right. That's when you do prop drilling. Anyway thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This your code causes program automatically insert a `semicolon` in the end of:

```
background-color: ${({ navItemsColor }) =>
```

So try always to add semicolons at the end of statements.

```
const TheSearchForm = styled.form`
input[type="text"]:focus {
background-color: ${({ navItemsColor }) =>
navItemsColor === "white" ? "black" : "white"};
}`;
```